# Android: Cannot login with facebook on a released apk

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hi I created an Android Application that has a Facebook Authentication. 
It is working when I directly installed the application using Eclipse to the device.

Then I wanted to share the apk so I followed this instructions:

```
1) Right click my project in Eclipse then Android Tools -> Export Unsigned Application Package 
2) Generate my release key store keytool -genkey -v -keystore release.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 
3) jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore release.keystore <apk-name> alias_name
4) jarsigner -verify <apk-name>
```

then I installed the released signed APK on my device.

I also enabled the facebook app and all its live features available to the general public.

**The problem is when I'm trying to login using Facebook it is not working.**

Comment: Is there any error message in logcat?

Comment: When your creating released apk , you got new hash key or SHA 1 now using this key you have to registered your app again then facebook is working with released apk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to generate new hash from new keystore you're using to sign release APK, and add it to your Facebook application.

Answer (score 1):

When something does not work in a release build, it is typically a ProGuard issue. Most likely it has renamed (obfuscated) some classes whose names are used in the application (this may include the internal classes).

PS please post the `adb logcat` log, it most likely shows what is going on!